# How to get text value of XML node when it has child nodes

Tags: python, lxml

I have scenario like this:

```
<fetch>
   <xyz:match selector="ph-%"/>
   tools.build.compiler
</fetch>
```

Now the XML node `<fetch>` has both child node and text value.
I want to extract the text value of `<fetch>` node.
I am using python and Lxml for parsing the XML.
I used the LXML's `element.text` but I am getting text value as `None`.
Can any one tell what mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `tail` member of the child.

```
def get_text(node):
    text = [node.text] + [child.tail for child in node]
    return ''.join(x for x in text if x is not None)
```

The schema you are using is a little weird.  LXML is designed to work with more traditional ways of encoding data into XML, although it supports general XML parsing the `.tail` usage will always be a little weird unless your schema are straightforward.